# Issue while comparing a long string with a string of array

Tags: java, arrays, string, contains

Main Idea: I have an URL (String) and I also have an Array with few data's (String). I want to check whether the strings inside of the Array are found in the URL or not using `contains()` method.

My code structure: First of all the string words are stored inside a text file. I will read that file and store the values inside a `JTextArea`. And from the `JTextArea` i use `getText()` method and storing the values inside an Array. And now, I will check the strings using `contains` method. Here is my code:

This function (Working fine) reads the text file and write inside the `JTextArea`.

```
JTextArea jta = new JTextArea(300,300);
Reader reader = null;
try {
    reader = new FileReader(new File("res/pass.txt"));
    jta.read(reader, "The force is strong with this one");
} catch (Exception exp) {
    exp.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        reader.close();
    } catch (Exception exp) {}
}
```

Wait before that, these are the words that stored inside the `pass.txt` earlier. Just example:

red~

green~

yellow~

black~

This function (Working fine) to know the length of Array.

```
String getArr="";
int getCount=0, z=0, lens = jta.getText().length();
for(int i=0; i<lens; i++){
    if(jta.getText().charAt(i)=='~'){
        getCount++;
    }
}
```

This function (Working fine) store the strings inside the Array.

```
String[] arr = new String[getCount];
for(int i=0; i<lens; i++){
    if(jta.getText().charAt(i)!='~'){
        getArr = getArr+jta.getText().charAt(i);
    }
    else{
        arr[z] = getArr; getArr=""; z++;
    }
}
```

The problem starts from here. I tried to print all the Array values in the console and it's displaying all the values. But, when I do the comparison it's not working as i expected.

```
String txtGetURL = txtURL.getText(); //The URL
Boolean ok=true;

for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
    System.out.print(arr[i]);
}
for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
    if(txtGetURL.toLowerCase().contains(arr[i].toLowerCase())){
       ok=false;
    }
}

if(ok==false){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "URL Blocked!"); 
}
else{
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Whitelist URL"); 
}
```

Let say, the sample URL I enter in the textfield is `http://www.example.com/ex/examplered.html` Instead of displaying `URL Blocked` it's displaying `Whitelist URL`. Please help me to solve my problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When dealing with `String` objects, there is no need to hand build your own parsing based on characters and indexes, there are many methods available to help.

Here, you'll likely want to use `split()` and `trim()`.

Initially you values are `red~` and then they are put into a text area, which will likely add some white space to it. So the value you eventually deal with could be:  `red ~ \n` or some variant.

So, first use `split()` on the `~` character and then use `trim()` on the first element of the resulting split array.

Here I've written a quick test class to show this in action:

```
public class BlockedWords {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        //Various different types of white space within the input.
        final String[] input = {" A ~\n\r","\n\rB ~","\nE\r~"," G\n~"};

        final String[] urls = {"www.url.com/A","www.url.com/B","www.url.com/C","www.url.com/D",
                "www.url.com/E","www.url.com/F","www.url.com/G","www.url.com/H"};

        final BlockedWords whiteListing = new BlockedWords(input);

        for (final String url : urls) {
            if( whiteListing.containsBlockedWord(url) ) {
                System.out.println(url + " is blocked.");
                continue;
            }
            System.out.println(url + " is whitelisted.");
        }
    }


    private String[] blockedWords;

    public BlockedWords(final String[] blockedWords) {
        for (int i = 0; i < blockedWords.length; i++) {
            //Split on the ~ character to get an array of {"word", ""} then just take the word. in index 0.
            //Then trim it in case there are any whitespace characters still around the word.
            blockedWords[i] = blockedWords[i].split("~")[0].trim();
        }

        this.blockedWords = blockedWords;
    }

    public boolean containsBlockedWord(final String url) {
        for (final String blockedWord : this.blockedWords) {
            if( url.toLowerCase().contains( blockedWord.toLowerCase() ) ) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

And the output is this:

> www.url.com/A is blocked.
>
> www.url.com/B is blocked.
>
> www.url.com/C is whitelisted.
>
> www.url.com/D is whitelisted.
>
> www.url.com/E is blocked.
>
> www.url.com/F is whitelisted.
>
> www.url.com/G is blocked.
>
> www.url.com/H is whitelisted.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this,

```
org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(txtGetURL , arr[i].trim());
```

By using this you can ignore the case and check if is it containing or not and also

If you sure that string  contains only letters you can clean it by

```
String resultString = arr[i].replaceAll("[^\\p{L}\\p{Nd}]+", "");
```

Comment: But I should say that be careful when you taking examples. Definitely you could change it before putting it to this site. It may not affect to question or code.

Comment: Thank you. I learned something new technique from your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is that your string in array contains line separator (`\n`)
In that case, because url does not contain it, `contains` method returns false.

To fix that, alter you code (I also suggest using `String.split()`, it is much simplier):

```
String[] arr = jta.getText().split("~");
```

and when you are checking, use `trim()` to avoid line separators:

```
if (txtGetURL.toLowerCase().contains(arr[i].trim().toLowerCase())) {
  ok = false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I just changed this line like this and it's working fine now. `arr[z] = getArr.trim(); getArr=""; z++;`